# Loading a graph from links lists takes a lot of time and memory

Tags: python, algorithm, graph

I'm working on graph analysis, and actually I'm new. I'm writing software to load graphs from link lists. My way of loading the graph is taking 50 seconds and 500MB for a graph with around 4200 vertices and 88234 edges/links. I was wondering if such a number is normal! My question: is there a better way for loading graphs?

Here's my attempt:

```
def read_graph(file_path):
    """
        Read a text file that has the following format: source target
    """
    edges_file_path = file_path
    graph = gt.Graph(directed=False)
    vertices_names_to_indices = {}
    with open(edges_file_path, 'r') as edges_file:
        for line in edges_file:
            line = line.rstrip()
            row = line.split(' ') 
            if len(row) != 2:
                raise Exception("There are more than two nodes in a row in the edges file!")
            source = row[0]
            target = row[1]
            sindex = None
            tindex = None

            if source in vertices_names_to_indices:
                sindex = vertices_names_to_indices[source]
            else:
                v1 = graph.add_vertex()
                sindex = int(v1)
                vertices_names_to_indices[source] = sindex

            if target in vertices_names_to_indices:
                tindex = vertices_names_to_indices[target]
            else:
                v2 = graph.add_vertex()
                tindex = int(v2)
                vertices_names_to_indices[target] = tindex

            graph.add_edge(sindex, tindex)
```

Comment: looks good to me.. Try running it with cprofile to see what is slowing it down. less than a million edges should take less than a second. would be curious to see the gt.graph implementation.

Comment: @robertking I'm using graph-tool.skewed.de. Is the 500MB normal for such a graph?!

Comment: looks ok to me to (fwiw). profile it as robert king recommends.

Comment: @dementedhedgehog is it normal to consume 500MB for such a graph?

Comment: 500MB suggests around 6KB per edge. It seems a bit high, but it's not clear what information is being stored along with the edges.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting vertices to integers? And why aren't you using `collections.defaultdict`? With that, and with simplifying some other parts of your code, I arrive at something like this:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def read_graph(file_path):
    """
        Read a text file that has the following format: source target
    """
    graph = gt.Graph(directed=False)
    vertices_names_to_indices = defaultdict(graph.add_vertex)
    with open(file_path, 'r') as edges_file:
        for line in edges_file:
            source, target = line.rstrip().split(' ')
            graph.add_edge(vertices_names_to_indices[source],
                           vertices_names_to_indices[target])
```

Since I don't have your edges file, I can neither test nor profile it.

Comment: Not bad.  If you want to speed up parsing the file, you can use `numpy.loadtxt()` to read it into an array very, very quickly, then just iterate over the rows as you do now.

Comment: graph.add_vertex() returns an object that needs to be converted to int()